# Duplicate questions appearing in google

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Is there a way that this can be prevented? Finding 4 questions or so that are dupes is a bit disconcerting when having to wade through them all!

Isn't there a meta tag that can be added to duplicate question pages to discourage search engines from indexing them thus linking directly to the original?

Comment: Sometimes the duplicates have different answers. It can be really useful to read through a few similar questions if you're trying to find an answer, especially if you're not sure of the correct wording.

Comment: The main problem is not the duplicates, but that Google picks up on the "Related" question section (the right column) and thus many answers get multiple hits in Google.

Comment: Sometimes the top result is exactly what I need and is marked as duplicate. If Google shuts it down, and my particular wording isn't able to retrieve what I'm looking for, then I'll likely end up posting a duplicate question again.

Answer (score 10):

No, the *point* of keeping duplicates around is to act as sign posts to the canonical post. The original post cannot ever cater to all spellings of the concept.

Hiding duplicates from search engines would **defeat that purpose**.

If you find a lot of duplicates that use the exact same wording and whose answers don't add anything to what is already said in the canonical post, we can perhaps clean up those duplicates by deleting them. But that only works for low-quality dupes with a low or even negative score.

Comment: So you'd rather pollute Google search results with duplicates because someone said "tomato" instead of "tomato" and the poor sap searching for the answer won't be able to tell the difference? I think Google is more intelligent than mere word detection in posts

Comment: @user3791372: because someone said *that red fruit you use in salads a lot or in pizza sauces* instead of *tomato*. This is about *concepts* not spelling mistakes. Someone searching for *tomato* will find the canonical outright.

Comment: I don't use that red fruit at all due to acid reflux, but you miss my point. If the answer appears in google, and _not_ 5 different ways to ask the question, it would be more beneficial to the person seeking the answer. If the closed dupes still appear on the site, but are discouraged from appearing in search results, the fact that the dupe question links to the original question would still cause the original to appear for "tomato" instead of "tomato".

Comment: @user3791372: no, you are missing my point; that sidebar only shows a few posts, not all of them, and none of their contents are going to be indexed. Hiding duplicates from search engines means that someone searching for *that red fruit* will **not find anything**, certainly not the canonical.

Comment: And besides, I'm sure Google is at a level where it wouldn't even need to link the user to the site, it could just show the accepted answer directly in the search results, completely bypassing all profit streams of the SE sites.

Comment: @martijnPeters Nope, t'is you failing to see it. Text B linking to Text A means that both A and B are related. E.g. the words used in B also relate to A. If question B is hidden, search engines will link directly to A for the words used in B, thus producing a better result for the seeker. It's basic site linking strategy

Comment: @user3791372: no, that's not how it works. You cannot 'hide' page B from search results but have it still count as a pointer to page A. Either page B is gone entirely from the index, or it is a viable search result. Do you know what spammers and SEO scammers would not give for such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

That's my experience too.  Questions that Google picks are often marked as duplicate.  In my experience the questions marked as inferior and duplicate have information that the originals do not. The supposed duplicates are far more valuable than the originals.

And many duplicate closes are just indefensible.  Here is [one I noticed this morning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318777/undo-a-particular-commit-in-git).

Duplicate closes are evil.  It's a good thing Google can ignore them and do the right thing.

Comment: Uhm, but google can't do the right thing - you said it yourself.

Comment: Google does the right thing.  It takes me to the high-quality question that SO thinks is a duplicate

Comment: Don't speak out against the 'popular' people's opinions or you'll be downvoted